# Why am I getting this error with my RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Videos#new

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `videos_path' for #<#<Class:0x10398f8d8>:0x10398dbc8>
```

I have one Video model and a videos controller with a `new` and `create` method. My `routes.db` file has `root :to => "videos#new"`. I have one view `new.html.erb` with this code:

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :video_url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :video_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my controller has this:

```
def new
 @video = Video.new
end

def create
@video = Video.new(params[:video])

respond_to do |format|
  if @article.save
    format.html #{ redirect_to(@video, :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
 end
end
```

This is all that's in my routes file:

```
 Dreamstill::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => "videos#new"
 end
```

Comment: ok posted, it's not much... that may be why I get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your routes should be

```
 Dreamstill::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => "videos#new"
   resources :videos
 end
```

Comment: hmmm, i actually tried this but it didn't work... but now it does. Thanks!

Comment: Key is the line `resources :videos`. That is what allows you to use `videos_path`, `new_video_path` etc. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for more.